# Evaluate limit with integral

Tags: integration, limits

The task is to evaluate: $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to +\infty}\int_{n}^{n+7}\frac{\sin x}{x}\mbox{d}x$.

I don't know how to approach this. $\displaystyle \int_{}^{}\frac{\sin x}{x}\mbox{d}x$ doesn't even express in elementary functions.

Comment: How about Taylor series?

Comment: Isn't the function getting awfully close to $0$? And the interval is not getting long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: use a comparison test $\bigl|\,\int_n^{n+7}{\sin x\over x}\,dx\,\bigr|\le \int_n^{n+7} \bigl|{\sin x\over x}\bigr|\,dx \le\int_n^{n+7} {1\over x} \,dx$.